# ReDim Preserve array to start at index 3

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I populate an array with a range, and would like to have the same field and record numbers in the array as on  the actual range.
In other words: if the array is derived from `A5:D10`, `myArr(5,2)` should refer to `B5`.

```
Dim myArr As Variant
myArr = sht.Range("A3:M" & LRow)

'Redesign array references
    'This works
    ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To LRow -2, 0 To 12)

    'This does not work
    ReDim Preserve myArr(3 To LRow, 1 To 13)
```

> Subscript out of range

The error message above suggest I may try to go out of bounds with the indexes, but they're the same size as the working indexes. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a multi dimensional array you can only redesign `ReDim` the last array dimension.

For example in a multi dimensional array you can do

```
Dim myArr(1 To 10, 1 To 20)
ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To 10, 1 To 25)
```

but you cannot do

```
Dim myArr(1 To 10, 1 To 20)
ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To 15, 1 To 20)
```

nor can you do

```
Dim myArr(1 To 10, 1 To 20)
ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To 10, 5 To 20)
```

or

```
Dim myArr(1 To 10, 1 To 20)
ReDim Preserve myArr(5 To 10, 1 To 20)
```

The documentation of the [ReDim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) says:

> *"If you use the `Preserve` keyword, you can resize only the last array dimension and you can't change the number of dimensions at all.
>
>   …
>
>   Similarly, when you use `Preserve`, you can change the size of the array only by changing the upper bound; changing the lower bound causes an error."*

The only solution to get around this would be to define a new array with the new dimensions and shift the data into this new array using a loop. But then the idea of loading a range of values into an array at once like

```
myArr = sht.Range("A3:M" & LRow).Value
```

is completly useless. Actually in this case loading the not needed data of the first 2 rows into the array too should be faster than shifting the array with a loop.

Use

```
myArr = sht.Range("A1:M" & LRow).Value
```

and you can use `myArr(5, 2)` to refer to `B5`. Loading the additional 2 lines into the array too should not make a big difference.

Comment: Ah shoot, I knew this too. Thanks for refreshing my memory